# Parametric equations for a line perpendicular to two given lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

We are given two lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$L1 : x = 4t  , y = 1-2t , z = 2+2t;\\ L2 : x = 1+t  , y = 1-t  ,  z = -1+4t.$

The question asked was to find the parametric equations for the line that is perpendicular to the lines L1 and L2 which passes through their point of intersection.

Could anyone help and kindly explain how to find this?

Comment: Calculate the point of intersection.  Take the cross product of the directional vectors of the two lines, this is the direction vector of the desired line.

Comment: @almagest the question is right and i have its solution also but it is too short don't explains it in a detailed way

Comment: @shivanshumanar Yes, so solving for $s,t$, the point of intersection is $(2,0,3)$. Now take any other point on $L_1$, say $(4,-1,4)$ so that the difference, the vector $(2,-1,1)$ lies along $L_1$. Similarly for $L_2$. Now, as Michael Hoppe says the cross product of those two vectors must be perpendicular to $L_1$ and $L_2$. So take the line in that direction through the point of intersection.